# PHP - object passed to if condition

Tags: php, object, type-conversion

What exactly is going on when you pass an object to an if, like this:

```
class TestClass {
  ...
}
$obj = new TestClass();

if($obj) { // what exactly is going on here ?
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your variable is an object, that will always be treated as `true`-  i.e. condition will always pass unless constructor of `TestClass` will not instantiate object for some reason. You can see [type-judging page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to see how PHP handles type-casting (in this case, casting to boolean type)

Comment: so what that expression will be always true no matter what ?

Comment: Yes, your variable will be treated as boolean - and in PHP all objects are trated as `true`. I.e. condition will always pass unless constructor of `TestClass` will not instantiate object for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It tells you,  if your `$obj` exists

Comment: NO it doesn't. Its just dirty and wrong way of using/assuming isset().

Answer (score 0):

php will convert your expression to boolean. Because this is an existing object, this will be converted to TRUE (From Php 5+, in php4 this will be converted to FALSE - I think ) :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting